# Filter by aggregated fields in JPA critera query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem writing a `Specification` which will sort by an aggregate.
Let's say I have 2 entities:

```
@Entity
public class Property {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Feedback> ratings;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Feedback {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer rating;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all the `Properties` with avarage rating above a given threshold. So here is what I came up with using the all mighty Google:

```
private static Specification<Property> ratingsSpec(Double minRating) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        ListJoin<Property, Feedback> feedbackJoin = root.join(Property_.ratings);
        return criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(criteriaBuilder.avg(feedbackJoin.get(Feedback_.rating)), minRating);
    };
}
```

But when trying to run that I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid use of aggregate function "AVG(CAST(FEEDBACK2_.RATING AS DOUBLE))"; 
SQL statement:
select property0_.id as id1_1_, property0_.additional_info as addition2_1_, property0_.address_line1 as address_3_1_, property0_.address_line2 as address_4_1_, property0_.city as city5_1_, property0_.postcode as postcode6_1_, property0_.area_sqm as area_sqm7_1_, property0_.rooms as rooms8_1_, property0_.type as type9_1_, property0_.version as version10_1_ from property property0_ inner join property_ratings ratings1_ on property0_.id=ratings1_.property_id inner join feedback feedback2_ on ratings1_.ratings_id=feedback2_.id where 1=1 and avg(cast(feedback2_.rating as double))>=3.9 [90054-199]
```

I copied the error exactly to not ommit anything important, obviously there are more fields there than I mentioned above.

Now, I see the problem with the query, the condition should definitely be in a `having` clause, not `where`, and I'm missing the `group by` clause. But how do I achieve that?
Any help will be appreciated.

Bonus question:
How do I sort by the same value? ;)

Comment: Specifications are intended for creating WHERE clauses dynamically, if you want to create arbitrary queries I recommend writing a custom method.

Comment: @JensSchauder thanks for the suggestion. I know that obviously, my case may seem absurd the way I presented it, but that was for the sake of simplicity. I am actually using this dynamically, creating them based on a filter object. All other conditions are indeed simple where clauses, that's the only one I had problems with. What would you suggest in such case?

Comment: I'd use a custom method implementation. But also since you found a solution, there is no real reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to do that using the query. I'm not positive if that's the best solution, so if anyone has some input I'm all ears. Here is the working solution:

```
private static Specification<Property> ratingsSpec(Double minRating) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            ListJoin<Property, Feedback> feedbackJoin = root.join(Property_.ratings);
            Expression<Double> avg = criteriaBuilder.avg(feedbackJoin.get(Feedback_.rating));
            return query.groupBy(root).having(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(avg, minRating)).getRestriction();
        };
    }
```